# How to run to undo an $unwind in mongodb and running a $match on an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using mongoDB Atlas to create a pipeline for an application.
This is my current pipeline

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'serverid': 11
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'runs', 
            'localField': 'discord_id', 
            'foreignField': 'advertiser', 
            'as': 'adRuns'
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'runs', 
            'localField': 'discord_id', 
            'foreignField': 'boosters', 
            'as': 'boosterRuns'
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$adRuns', 
            'includeArrayIndex': 'string', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': False
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            'adRuns._id': {
                '$gte': ObjectId('5f91d6d83119c516d8e2c364')
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            'adRuns._id': {
                '$lte': ObjectId('5f91ffffffffffffffffffff')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I unwind an array of objects in order to run matches that only return objects between two points in time using the hexadecimal ObjectId(_id)'s

Now I need to put the objects back in an array in order to run a $sum for each individual user that these runs are associated to, which I've tried to do but have been unable to.

For reference I will leave an example document for both my "Users" and "Runs" collections
USERS:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f8f1fa7b5212c7388bbae71"
    },
    "discord_id": "85479273153966080",
    "username": "Chille#9733",
    "character": "Chillelight",
    "server": "illidan",
    "serverid": 11
}
```

RUNS:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f91d6d03119c516d8e2c365"
    },
    "advertiser": "85479273153966080",
    "adType": "legendary",
    "typeOfBoost": "mythic_plus",
    "goldAmmount": "250000",
    "server": "tichondrius",
    "serverID": 6,
    "boosters": ["85479273153966080", "131939237468700672", "85479273153966080", "131939237468700672"],
    "boosterCut": 48437.5,
    "advertiserCut": 62500,
    "communityCut": 139062.5
}
```

Thank you so much!

Expected result would be to have an array of all the run objects once again so that I can sum boosterCut, advertiserCut, or communityCut with a simple $addField and $sum

Comment: _"I need to put the objects back in an array in order to run a $sum..."_: You can try using the `$group` and `$sum` ($sum can be used within a $group).

Comment: Tried this, the problem with group is that I don't have a sign user._id that I want to be grouping, which $group seems to require.

Comment: You can group on `username` field (or user's unique id field). Even to put the objects back into an array, you need to use `$group` (along with `$push` aggregation operator).  I am not sure I understand your comment fully.

Comment: @JoshuaBroussard Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

Its not required to unwind `adRuns` array you can try,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `adRuns` array, input empty values in required fields, sum values using `$add` and merge objects with current using `$mergeObjects`

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      adRunsSum: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$adRuns",
          initialValue: {
            boosterCut: 0,
            communityCut: 0,
            advertiserCut: 0
          },
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$value",
              {
                boosterCut: {
                  $add: ["$$this.boosterCut", "$$value.boosterCut"]
                },
                communityCut: {
                  $add: ["$$this.communityCut", "$$value.communityCut"]
                },
                advertiserCut: {
                  $add: ["$$this.advertiserCut", "$$value.advertiserCut"]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ucSFNs5rccR)